# Function posting in offset cell

Tags: excel, vba

I created a function that uses the Bing API to get coordinates.

How do I offset said results? The goal is to call the function whenever and it would post the results next to the selected Range.

For example, you type the address in A1, you call the function `CoordinatesBing(A1)` in the B1 cell, then it posts the results of the search in B1 and C1.

**Note:** This is a test to see if I can get the coordinates. Later I will introduce workflows and error catching.

```vb
Option Explicit
Const bingURL As String = "http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?query="
Const apiKey As String = "BingsMapKey"
Private Const ReadyOk As Long = 4

Public Function CoordinatesBing(reqAddress As String) As String
Dim URL As String
Dim reqHTTP As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim xmlAddress As String
Dim Latitude As Variant
Dim Longitude As Variant
Dim Result As Range

xmlAddress = WorksheetFunction.EncodeURL(reqAddress)'turns the selected range to Uri encoding

'Makes the request to BingMap
URL = bingURL & xmlAddress & "&o=xml" & "&key=" & apiKey
reqHTTP.Open "GET", URL, False
reqHTTP.send ("")

'Stores the coordinated in these variables.
Latitude = WorksheetFunction.FilterXML(reqHTTP.responseText,"/Response/ResourceSets/ResourceSet/Resources/Location/Point/Latitude")
Longitude = WorksheetFunction.FilterXML(reqHTTP.responseText, "/Response/ResourceSets/ResourceSet/Resources/Location/Point/Longitude")

'This is where I am having difficulties. 
Set Result = ' selects the cell here. I assume
'Post the results
Result.Offset(0, 2).Value = Latitude
Result.Offset(0, 3).Value = Longitude
 
End Function
```

Comment: To my understanding, a function can only present a result in the cell that it is in. Not overwrite the information in other cells. If you want to do this, you need to run it as a macro instead.

Comment: If Result is `"A1:A100"`, what is the expected cell for `Result.Offset(0, 2)`?

Comment: @ChristoferWeber honestly I just put that text not understanding what it actually does. I guess what I am trying to do is when you call the function "CoordinatesBing(A1)" for example then it post the results of the search in B1 and C1.
I'll edit the post to reflect that. Like I said I do not know what to search for.

Answer (score 1):

You need to think of it in terms of a function returning only one value. So your function definition would be more like

```
Public Function CoordinatesBing(ByVal reqAddress As String, ByVal lWhich As Long) As String
    
    'do stuff
    
    If lWhich = 0 Then
        CoordinatesBing = latitude
    Else
        CoordinatesBing = longitude
    End If
    
End Function
```

You would call that with a zero for cell B1 and a one for cell c1. That stinks because http calls are expensive and you have to call the function twice to get both coordinates.

You could write the formula as an array formula. Then you'd only have to call the API once, but your users would have to know to enter the formula with both cells selected and use Ctrl+Shift+Enter. Not ideal. Array formula UDFs look like this

```
Public Function CoordinatesBing(ByVal reqAddress As String) As String()
        
        Dim sreturn(0 To 1) As String
        
        sreturn(0) = "long"
        sreturn(1) = "lat"
        
        CoordinatesBing = sreturn
  
End Function
```

Those parens at the end of the Function declaration line tell it that it's returning an array.

A third option if you have only a limited number of addresses, is to generate a table using a Sub procedure for every address then use a built-in lookup function to get the coordinates from the table.

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying! This makes sense!!